# Objects having a specified attribute with common value, trigger a rule. The common value is not known and cannot be hardcoded in the rule file

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm

Let us say we have many Person() objects with two attributes "Zipcode" and "Name" . I want a rule to fire for all the objects  which have same value for the "Zipcode" attribute, only once.
As an example if there are 10 Person objects p1,p2.....p10 such that 5 Person objects have Zipcode = 1 and other 5 Person objects which have Zipcode = 2 , then I want a rule which will get triggered twice , i.e once for all Person objects with Zipcode =1  and once more for all Person objects with Zipcode =2 .

Answer (score 0):

```
rule "once for each zipcode"
when
   $zcs: Set() from accumulate( Person($h: zipcode), collectSet($h) )
   $zipcode: Object() from $zcs
   $ps: List() from collect( Person( zipcode == $zipcode ) )
then
   //...
end
```

Comment: Thank You . Works perfectly well.